# jQuery UI images?

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-plugins

I'm using the [jQuery datatables plugin](http://www.datatables.net/) (which is awesome BTW), but the default UI & images don't match or work too well with what I have. I've tried adding jQuery UI to my project and using it - but it looks like it might be a little heavy handed for what I want (mainly to use the sort & pagination icons). However, it looks like the icons in jQuery UI are all in one image...interesting.

My question is, how can I use the individual icons from the jQuery UI plugin in my project?

TIA

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's one image by design. It's a technique called [Image Sprites](http://www.w3schools.com/css/css_image_sprites.asp) that's used to reduce the number of resources to download to the client. You should use CSS to only show one icon in the image sprite.

Comment: I think that's what I've been trying to figure out. I figured there was a term out there that I did not know.

Answer (score 2):

you need to add the correct classes:

- class ui-icon - sets the size of the
  div to 16x16
- class ui-state-x - picks the color
- class ui-icon-yyy - specificies the 'offset' within the .png for the upper left corner of 16x16 grid

> ```
> <div class="ui-icon ui-state-default ui-icon-plus">&nbsp;</div>
> <div class="ui-icon ui-state-active ui-icon-plus">&nbsp;</div>
> <div class="ui-icon ui-state-error ui-icon-plus">&nbsp;</div>
> ```

Comment: the different icons available are in the 'demo.html' page in the jquery-ui zip file you originally downloaded.